# Buffer Overflow issue in Asp.net site

Tags: asp.net, reportviewer, buffer-overflow

I have a Report viewer control kept in the Asp.net page .

```
    <telerik:RadPageView runat="server" ID="rdPgView">
<div>
<rsweb:ReportViewer ID="reportViewer" runat="server" Width="100%" Height="100%" ShowWaitControlCancelLink="true" SizeToReportContent="False" AsyncRendering="True" ShowBackButton="false" ShowZoomControl="false" ShowPageNavigationControls="false" ShowCredentialPrompts="false"></rsweb:ReportViewer>
                   <br />
                               </div>
                            </telerik:RadPageView>
```

We found the below code code being generated . reportViewer is the name of the control . I have no clue how this gets generated . Our testing team mentioned that this could lead to Buffer Overflow .

```
   ctl00%24contentContent%24reportViewer%24ctl07%24store: AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
```

I am not sure how to control this .Do anyone have any idea of this .

Thanks,
Bala

Comment: try setting AsyncRendering attribute to false

Comment: Whats is the error message that you get ?

Comment: @Aristos , We are not getting any error . We are trying to find out the reason behind the values for   ctl00%24contentContent%24reportViewer%24ctl07%24store . Is this related to ViewState ? Can this be controlled . Our testing tool is picking this up as Buffer overflow .

Comment: @Aristos , The Reportviewer used is not from Telerik . Its a .Net component .

Comment: The A is the issue , I have some reportviewer controls kept above it where the store is set to Null ( Not sure how and why ) . But this is the only reportviewer in my whole project that has this "A" value . Unable to figure out the reason